# Quickly resetting user data on Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I spend about half of my day debugging sometimes by deleting Firebase users, going through the sign-up process, validating the e-mail, etc so I can accurate recreate the conditions that led to the error.

I'm planning to write a function to do this for me automatically, but before I do I wanted to ask if there were any functions to make this easier? Maybe there's already a "reset user data" function that wouldn't require me to manually upload a blank JSON or delete the authentication info?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no one click reset Firebase Authentication data button. You would have to write functions to both write and delete users. I've written a Scheduled Cloud function that deletes users every midnight in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67150606/13130697). You can similarly write one for adding users using createUser method of Admin SDK.

If this is for development purpose you can try using Firebase emulators.